# Any symmetry that fixes three non-collinear points is the identity

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, isometry

I am asked to finish the following sentence:

Let $\sigma$ be an isometry on $\mathbb{R}^2$, suppose it fixes the points $A$ and $B$

Suppose $\sigma$ also fixes a third point $C$ which is not on the line $AB$.

Complete the
following sentence: If $P$ is a fourth point in the plane which is not fixed by $\sigma$,
so $\sigma(P) \neq P$, then $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all on the $\dots$  BLANK

This is a contradiction and
so $\sigma(P) = P$. Since P is arbitrary, we conclude that $\sigma$ is the identity.

**I am not entirely sure what the author is going for. I think what they want is to make the case that $A,B$ and $C$ are on same reflection line, but I do not see how. This would contradict $C$ not being on the line through $AB$. It just seems like the argument skips a step**

Comment: My initial instinct on reading this is that there is an error in the assignment, and "which is not on the line $AB$" should not have been there. Then you could fill "same line" into the BLANK.

Comment: Yeah that's precisely the contradiction part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the term for the blank space would be *bisection* of the segment $P, \sigma(P)$, since $d(P,X)=d(\sigma(P), X)$ for each $X\in\{A, B, C\}$.

And it is indeed a contradiction, as the next line says, and that finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you, I had trouble finding the right word for it too. How considerate of you.